# Visual Studio 2015 не видит Microsoft.Office.Interop

Tags: com, office, visual-studio-2015

*Visual Studio 2015* не видит `Microsoft.Office.Interop` при работе с *Microsoft Office 2016*.
Сборка `Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library` подключена. С пространством имён `Microsoft.Office.Core` всё нормально, но `Microsoft.Office.Interop` не видит вообще.

В чём может быть причина?

Comment: что значит не видит? в коде есть using Microsoft.Office.Interop; но при компиляции выдает ошибку?

Comment: @Stack, о чём и речь. Пространство имён не найдено.

Answer (score 1):

### Частичное решение проблемы

Пока проблему удалось разрешить, но, к сожалению, пока **частично**.

Вследствие пока невыясненных причин, в процессе установки необходимые сборки не попали в глобальный кэш (GAC). Поэтому, для *Excel* необходимую сборку нашёл в папке пакета и подключил оттуда.
Расположение папки:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\VFS\ProgramFilesX86\Microsoft Office\Office16\DCF
```

Там же можно найти сборку и для *Access*.

Сборку для *Outlook* нашёл здесь:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\ADDINS\Microsoft Power Query for Excel Integrated\bin
```

### Как отличить нужные сборки от всех остальных?

*(Информация скорее для тех, кто в будущем, возможно, будет читать этот ответ)*

Сборки предназначенные для работы с *Office* из .NET имеют характерное название:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.{Имя_приложения}.dll
```

То есть, для *Excel* сборка будет называться:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll
```

### UPDATE 08.01.2016 Окончательное решение проблемы

В конечном итоге **проблема полностью разрешилась** сама собой путём установки "чистого" *Microsoft Office 2016* "с нуля". Ранее было просто выполнено обновление с версии *2010* (видимо прошло некорректно).